# Synonym for touch the ground

Tags: synonyms

The intended meaning of the sentence is "They all fell to the ground, their heads touching the ground reverentially".

The sentence is - "They all fell to the ground, their heads (in line with or parallel to) the ground.

I want to say something to the effect that their heads were touching the ground in such a way that it felt as if the face were an extension of the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**prostrate**

> verb (used with object), prostrated, prostrating.
>
> 1. to cast (oneself) face down on the ground in humility, submission, or adoration.
> 2. to lay flat, as on the ground.
> 3. to throw down level with the ground.

[Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prostrate)

Comment: It was not your answer but rather the word in the definition of your answer which I was looking for. "Level" - They all fell to the ground, their heads level with it... Still marking as answer

Answer (score 1):

In a context of expressing reverence it possible to say **to fall on your face** or **to fall facedown**. Some examples from the Bible:

> And Abram [fell on his face](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2017%3A1-3&version=KJV): and God talked with him...
>
> Then Moses and Aaron [fell on their faces](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2014%3A5&version=KJV) before all the assembly of
>   the congregation of the children of Israel.

You can also consider **to fall *flat* on your face**.

> to fall so that you are lying on your chest on the ground

(Longman)

But note that **to fall *flat* on one's/something's face** or simply **to fall *flat*** can be also used figuratively meaning failure:

> 2. to fail completely, especially in an embarrassing way
>
> *This scheme will fall flat on its face unless the residents get behind it.*

(http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fall-flat-on-your-face)

Comment: Thanks but this has a negative connotation implying that either someone pushed them or clumsiness...I want to show that the action was willingly done.

Comment: No, no pushing or clumsiness implied. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: "fall" often implies accidental rather than intentional, hence using a term like kowtow, which carries in it the intentionalilty of the act, is better than any usage of "fell".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I guess context is king. In the Bible passages above there's no ambiguity whatsoever. But I'm not arguing that *fall on one's face* is the best option every time. Merely an option. Personally, I like *prostrate*. Then again, *fall on one's face* is the simplest, and even children would easily understand it. In that respect I'd argue it's the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest 'to kowtow'. The noun sense is

> The Chinese custom of touching the ground with the forehead in the act of prostrating oneself, as an expression of extreme respect, submission, or worship.

[From "kow-tow | kotow, n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104417 (accessed October 23, 2015).]

But the verb probably works better in your example sentence:

> a. intr. To perform the kow-tow. Also transf.

[From "kow-tow | kotow, v.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104418 (accessed October 23, 2015).]

So,

> They all fell to the ground, *kowtowing*.

If, however, you want to use the noun 'kowtow', this works:

> They all fell to the ground, performing the *kowtow*.

Whether either form will work depends on the context. Use of this borrowing from Chinese may be uncomfortable in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

They *prostrated themselves [in unison], becoming [as it were] one with the ground.*